# Unable to find 'Microsoft.Net.Http' package in VS 2013

Tags: c#, nuget

I'm trying to install Microsoft.Net.Http Package from Nuget in VS Studio 2013 with Update 4

> PM Install-Package Microsoft.Net.Http

Getting the following error:

```
Install-Package : Unable to find package 'Microsoft.Net.Http'.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.Net.Http
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

Comment: Some questions: What nuget feed are you using? What version of .NET is your project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could include `using System.Net.Http;`
It's the same package.
I've added the NuGet-package Microsoft.Net.Http via the Package Manager Console/GUI, but it references to System.Net.Http.